# Uploaded image is not getting cropped

Tags: php, image, crop, image-resizing

I want to upload an image using Android application, through PHP web services. The image is getting uploaded but
    when I want to crop the uploaded image, its failing. file_exixts condition returns true.
    Same thing I have tried in my website and its successfully uploading and cropping image.

```
include_once('../crop1.php'); // for cropping an image
include_once('../config.php'); // for encrypting the name of the image

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); 
$filename = $_REQUEST['photo'];
$binary = base64_decode($filename);
$encrypted_name = name_encrypt($filename); // encrypting the name of the image

$final = "../upload/".$encrypted_name."jpg"; // Its attaching the extension to the image.

$file = fopen($final, 'wb'); // commented the original code

fwrite($file, $binary); // storing image to the folder


if (file_exists($final))  //checking if image exists
{
    crop_medium($encrypted_name.'jpg'); // if image exists then crop it by calling this function in the included file crop1.php
    $query = "INSERT INTO `error_log` (`param1`, `param2`, `date_time`) VALUES ('1', 'success_found', '2013-07-08')";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
} 

$return["status"] = "OK";
$return["message"] = "Uploaded successfully";

echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

in crop1.php I've following code

```
<?php
function crop_medium($image_name)
{   
    include_once("resize-class.php"); // calling the php file to resize an uploaded image from the upload folder
    $resizeObj = new resize("upload/$encrypted_name"); 

    $resizeObj -> resizeImage(167, 121, 'crop'); // resizing and image in the given format

    $crop_image = "$encrypted_name";
    $resizeObj -> saveImage("cropped/$crop_image", 100); // saving resized image in other folder
}
?>
```

I edited my question. I was passing full path in the parameter, now I am passing only image name through the parameter. Please help me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is $encrypted_name..?

Comment: I am encrypting the name of the image before storing it to my server. And the function which will encrypt the image is called in the config.php file

Answer (score 0):

The patermeter variable your passing to the function

```
<?php
function crop_medium($image_name_with_full_path)
{
```

is not what your using in the function.

```
$resizeObj = new resize("upload/$encrypted_name");
```

Comment: Please consider that as an image name only. I tried by passing the full path also. But now I am searching for the image name in the upload folder in crop1.php, hence I am just passing the image name through the parameter.